# How can I create a ModelViewSet for my Customer and Order Models in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have a Customer Model.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

and a OrderItem Model.

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    ready = 1
    on_its_way = 2
    delivered = 3
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (ready, 'ready'),
        (on_its_way, 'on its way'),
        (delivered, 'delivered'),
    )
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)
```

I created another model ByCustomer Model

```
class ByCustomer(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    orders = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to turn it into a ModelViewSet where it only shows the orders of the selected Customer.

```
class By_Customer_View(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # code let's you select only one customer
    # and returns all the Orders that customer has
```

I've seen something like this for @api_view

```
 @api_view(['GET'])
 def by_customer(request, pk):
     tasks = ByCustomer.objects.get(name=pk)
     serializer = ByCustomerSerializer(tasks, many=False)
     return Response(serializer.data)
```

How would this work with ModelViewSet? I can't add extra parameters on (viewsets.ModelViewSet, pk). What other fields should I add and what am I missing? Still new to ModelViewSets so I don't know its limitations. If ModelViewSet doesn't have a solution to this. What do I need to change in the above @api_view code? Thanks.

Comment: Override the `get_queryset()` method of modelviewset.

Comment: What do you mean? What is the query set being overridden with?